# Transparency background color in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, background-color

This probably has a really easy fix, but who knows since it is IE.

I use a transparency background-color for my nav bar here http://codingbybrandon.com/highlandscafe-new/index.php This works just fine in Chrome and firefox, but not in IE. Any suggestions on how to fix this? The nav bar is also a sticky nav you will notice, so in IE when you start to scroll, the transparency appears.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using [8 digits hexD](https://css-tricks.com/8-digit-hex-codes/) code for `background-color`, most of the browsers including IE doesn't support it yet. Check [here](https://caniuse.com/#search=hex)

```
#mainNav {
    background-color: #121517e6;
}
```

Use can use `rgba` instead.

```
#mainNav {
    background-color: rgba(18, 21, 23, 0.9);
}
```

Comment: I am by no means no front in developer, so thank you for pointing that out. There's more freelance work for sites like this, so I'm learning.